# How can I plot a histogram in pandas using nominal values?

Tags: pandas, histogram

Given:

```
ser = Series(['one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'two'])
```

How do I plot a basic histogram of these values?

Here is an ASCII version of what I'd want to see in matplotlib:

```
     X
 X   X   X
-------------
one two three
```

I'm tired of seeing:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could use the [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) method:

```
In [10]: ser.value_counts()
Out[10]: 
two      3
one      1
three    1
```

and then [plot this as a bar chart](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#bar-plots):

```
ser.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

Edit: I noticed that this doesn't keep the desired order. If you have a list/Series for this ordering (in this case `ser[:3]` will do) you can [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) before plotting:

```
In [12]: ser.value_counts().reindex(ser[:3])
Out[12]: 
one      1
two      3
three    1
```

Comment: An alternative is to use the [seaborn](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) `countplot`.